Solution for the radial function of a static Klein-Gordon equation with $(r^3-v)^\frac{1}{3}$ terms
I am searching for a solution of a 2nd order differential equation describing the radial part of a static Klein-Gordon equation.
See the following static Klein-Gordon equation
(1) $\qquad Tr( \ g^{-1} \cdot H(\psi) \ )+\mu \ \psi = 0$
with $\mu=\frac{M^2 c^2}{\hbar}-\frac{k^2}{c^2}$ where $g^{-1}$ is the inverse metric of the related coordinate system and $H(\psi)$ is the Hessian of $\psi$. The constant $\mu$ depends on the mass $M$, speed of light $c$, $\hbar$ and a constant $k$. The dimension of $\mu$ is $m^{-2}$. $Tr$ is the trace.
With $g=-diag(1,1,1)$ and the Hessian $\left(\matrix{\partial_x\\\partial_y\\\partial_z}\right)\cdot\left(\matrix{\partial_x \psi \ \partial_y \psi \ \partial_z \psi}\right) = \nabla \cdot \nabla^T$ equation (1) becomes
(2) $\qquad -\Delta \psi + \mu \psi = 0$
where $\Delta$ is the Laplace Operator in cartesian coordinates.
With $g = -diag(1,r^2,r^2 sin^2 \theta)$ and $\nabla = (J^{-1})^T \cdot \left(\matrix{\partial_r\\\partial_\theta\\\partial_\phi}\right)$ with the Jacobi matrix
(3) $\qquad J=\left(\matrix{sin \theta \ cos \phi & r \ cos \theta \ cos \phi & - r \ sin \theta \ sin \phi\\sin \theta \ sin \phi & r \ cos \theta \ sin \phi & r \ sin \theta \ cos \phi\\cos \theta &-r \ sin \theta & 0}\right)$
the Laplace operator in (2) is in spherical coordinates.
With this introduction now let us assume, the metric is $g = -diag\left(\left(1-\frac{v}{r^3}\right)^{-\frac{4}{3}},r^2 \left(1-\frac{v}{r^3}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}},r^2 sin^2 \theta \left(1-\frac{v}{r^3}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}\right)$, where $v$ is a constant volume and with the Jacobi matrix in (3) equation (1) becomes
(4) $\qquad -\left(1-\frac{v}{r^3}\right)^{\frac{4}{3}} \partial_r^2 \psi - \frac{2}{r \left(1-\frac{v}{r^3}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}} \partial_r \psi - \frac{1}{r^2 \left(1-\frac{v}{r^3}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}}\left[\partial_\theta^2 \psi + \frac{cos \theta}{sin \theta} \partial_\theta \psi + \frac{1}{sin^2 \theta} \partial_\phi^2 \psi\right] + \mu \psi = 0$
It is possible to separate this differential equation in (4) with the Ansatz:
(5) $\qquad \psi(r,\theta,\phi)=R(r)P(\theta)\Phi(\phi)$
which leads to the differential equations
(6) $\qquad \frac{1}{\Phi(\phi)} \partial_\phi^2 \Phi(\phi) = - m^2$
with the solution $\Phi(\phi) = C_1 cos(m\phi)+C_2 sin(m\phi)$ and
(7) $\qquad sin \theta \ \frac{1}{P(\theta)} \partial_\theta \left(sin \theta \ \partial_\theta P(\theta) \right) - m^2 = -\lambda \ sin^2 \theta$
with the solution $P(\theta) = C_1 \ P_l^m (cos \theta) + C_2 \ Q_l^m (cos \theta)$ with $l=\frac{1}{2}\left(-1+\sqrt{1+4\lambda}\right)$ where $P_l^m(cos\theta)$ is the Associated Legendre Polynomial and $Q_l^m(cos\theta)$ is the Associated Legendre Function of the second kind and
(8) $\qquad -\left(1-\frac{v}{r^3}\right)^{\frac{4}{3}} \partial_r^2 R(r) - \frac{2}{r \left(1-\frac{v}{r^3}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}} \partial_r R(r) + \left(\frac{1}{r^2 \left(1-\frac{v}{r^3}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}} \lambda + \mu \right) R(r) = 0$
which is the differential equation for the radial function, which is still unsolved. The constants $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are arbitrary and can be adapted to the solution. The solution obviously is different for the interesting inner region $0 \le r \le v$ with $R(v)=0$ and outer region $v \le r < \infty $
Equation (8) can be transformed to the canonical equation with the Ansatz $R(r)=u(r) \ \left(\frac{v}{r^3-v} \ e^{\frac{v}{r^3-v}} \right)^{\frac{1}{3}}$ to
(9) $\qquad \frac{\left(r^3-v\right)^{3}}{r} \partial_r^2 u(r) - \frac{r^3}{\left(r^3-v\right)} \left(\left(r^3-v\right)^2 \left(\lambda + \left(r^3-v\right)^{\frac{2}{3}} \mu \right) -4 v r^3 + 5v^2 \right) u(r) = 0$
It is also possible to transform equation (8) to the Riccati equation with the Ansatz $y(r)=\frac{\partial_r R(r)}{R(r}$ to
(10) $\qquad \partial_r y(r) + y(r)^2 + \frac{2 r^5}{\left(r^3-v\right)^{2}} y(r) = \frac{r^4}{\left(r^3-v\right)^{2}} \lambda + \frac{r^4}{\left(r^3-v\right)^{\frac{4}{3}}} \mu $
Example of a solution attempt
Let us assume, the solution of the Riccati equation (10) is of type
(11) $\qquad y(r) = a \left(r^3-v\right)^{\frac{k}{3}} + b \left(r^3-v\right)^{\frac{l}{3}}$
The related equation to be solved is:
(12) $\qquad 2 r^5 \left( a \left(r^3-v\right)^{\frac{k}{3}} + b \left(r^3-v\right)^{\frac{l}{3}} \right) + r^2 \left(r^3-v\right) \left( a k \left(r^3-v\right)^{\frac{k}{3}} + b l \left(r^3-v\right)^{\frac{l}{3}} \right) + \left(r^3-v\right)^2 \left( a \left(r^3-v\right)^{\frac{k}{3}} + b \left(r^3-v\right)^{\frac{l}{3}} \right)^2 = r^4 \left( \lambda + \left(r^3-v\right)^{\frac{2}{3}} \mu \right)$
The challenge is to find with a non-trivial set of variables $a,b,k,l,\lambda,\mu$, which fulfills equation (12).
Maybe someone has an idea how to find this solution or any other solution of (8), (9) or (10).
